# How to store authentication details for local client application

Tags: azure, authentication

I am creating an application for our clients to use on their local servers. The application needs to communicate with an azure service bus. I need to store credentials in the application to send and receive messages to the service bus. I also plan to encrypt the messages before send, and decrypt in the app locally.

I cannot find a secure way of storing the service bus connection string and the decryption password (or salt) in the local application. I have thought about storing in an Azure key vault but then I would need to store the url, secret and object Id.

I could store the password in the app config but then would need to encrypt but then would need to store the decryption details. I cannot use protected app config as it needs to work on multiple external client servers. I cannot use AAD as I dont want to have to add client user accounts in my AAD (and also grant them access to the service bus or kv).

How is it best to store passwords/secrets in a local application? App config would require encryption then how would I store the decryption details?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Host your own web API that communicates with the bus (encryption is then for free if you use HTTPS, which you should anyway). Authentication with this service can then be done in any manner you please (simple API key, OAuth or even IP whitelist) and will not require secure storage of credentials, at least no more secure than your client needs it (they would be allowed to know the credentials). Secure storage of credentials that don't need to be hidden from clients is a much easier problem; on Windows this can be done with DPAPI, for example (exposed through the `ProtectedData` class).

Comment: If I follow you correctly, create an API that communicates with the backend. Then store the authentication details to that API in config then encrypt the config with DPAPI. How do you encrypt the config before sending to client? I can encrypt on first run but there would be a time when its left in plain text in the config file?

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the config initially because the client is allowed to know their API key (it's secret only to that client, in the sense that they shouldn't share it with others, and if they do you can invalidate it). Ideally you do need to communicate it securely initially (e-mail is usually not encrypted, but could be, also people usually have far more things to worry about than an API key if someone is reading all corporate mail). The DPAPI part is just so the key is secure on the client machine once it's arrived.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. generate a key per client and send that to them. Thanks for your help @JeroenMostert :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have a secret value securely on an untrusted device is to first encrypt it in a trusted device (a server under your control for example).
But Azure Service Bus won't accept an encrypted key.

So you have a couple options:

1. Make a client-specific authorization key in Service Bus and give it to the client with the app.

   - The key can have Send or Listen rights or both
   - This can be at namespace level to give the same access to all queues and topics or it can be in a single queue/topic
2. Make a back-end app that the client app calls instead of the client app interacting with Service Bus directly. You would have to figure out how to do to authenticate the client apps though.

Comment: if I encrypt a secret on a trusted device, wouldnt I have to store the decryption value in the code still? And there it still be unsecure? 
Ive currently gone down the queue specific SAS and stored that value in code. But it doesnt "feel" like the correct approach still.

Comment: The issue is that since your client app runs on an untrusted device, the app itself cannot authenticate securely. Only the user could, but you mentioned you can't use AAD authentication. You're correct on the encrypted secret, it would require that it is not decrypted on the client but sent as is to the server, which would then decrypt it. But Service Bus does not support it.